# How to retrieve AWS IAM role details filtered using its tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

Is there any way to retrieve IAM role ARN or Name using its TAGS. I tried in ansible module, unfortunately that doesn't support filter parameter to filter tags.

So do we have any such kind in AWS CLI, listing out the tags of roles and retrieving the necessary details like ARN or Name from them?

Earlier I had this `resourcegroupstaggingapi` to filter out the resources based out of tags. But for IAM I am not sure I could filter out. Only IAM policies using below CLI

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region us-east-1 --resource-type-filters iam:policy
```

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong in this question and what I am missing to get negative votes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation where I want to fetch all my resources based on tags. Sadly `resourcegroupstagging` only support some service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/supported-services.html

My workaround has been to explicitly name my roles and then use the get_role which takes name as input.